# tsql permission

Tags: t-sql, permissions

I need to configure restricted permissions on sql server 2008 to a specified user as following :

- read from tables
- write into tables
- create views
- drop views ( created by this user )

The given user must not be able to drop tables, functions, sps.

Answer (score 0):

> Read from all tables -> Assign
>   db_datareader role
>
> Write into all tables -> Assign
>   db_datawriter role

Read permission on a few tables

```
Grant Select To <Username> on <tablename>
```

Create view

```
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO <Username>;
```

To Delete View you should explicitly give viewname like

```
GRANT Delete VIEW TO <Username> On <TableName>
```

If you want some details on this you should read through : [This microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your response, but "GRANT Delete VIEW TO <Username> On <TableName>" doesn't work at all.